# Create multiple records for middle table in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have 2 tables of users and publishers and I have a middle table user_publishers.

I have added this middle table in active admin and all is working fine.

I have added the select2 plugin so I can select multiple records from dropdown. I want to create multiple records like below

[image]

I am getting these request parameters in logs

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ia1FXjr8JstEri0fF44YE2wSC9VeCoFoLqVXzFohHZGREiCEfN1G5hzMFUAb+AQLAUURCoqxNb6z8IW1uz/J4A==", "user_publisher"=>{"user_id"=>["", "2", "1"], "publisher_id"=>["", "1"]}, "commit"=>"Create User publisher"}
```

How can I achieve it?  I don't want to add too much custom code.

Comment: Could you clarify what exact behaviour do you want to achieve? When having 2 users and 2 publishers selected you expect to create 4 UserPublisher records (each possible pair)? cheers

Comment: Yes.. that's correct.. that's what i am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I can't think of any sophisticated solution, most naive approach would be controller action like:

```
def create
    params[:user_publisher][:user_id].each do |user_id|
      params[:user_publisher][:publisher_id].each do |publisher_id|
        UserPublisher.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id, publisher_id: publisher_id)
      end
    end
end
```

Also, make sure to remove `""` values from `user_ids` and `publisher_ids`